# Rails - how to perform a math function in a view helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my view helper method, I want to be able to calculate the range between two numbers. Right now I am doing this:

```
def show_range
 max = @shirts.get_max
 min = @shirts.get_min
 max-min
end
```

I know that max and min are working because I can just print each of their values out. However, when I try to do this simply math function in my "module ShirtsHelper", I get the following error:

```
undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
```

Why am I getting this error and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because your `max` variable is `nil` and there is no matching method `-` on `nil`. You could check whether min and max are not `nil` with `max - min if max && min`. However, I guess you might want to provide a fallback value (e.g. 0) in this case, so you might be looking for something like this

```
def show_range
  max = @shirts.get_max
  min = @shirts.get_min

  if max && min
    max - min
  else
    0 # Fallback value
  end
end
```

Or even more concise:

```
def show_range
  max = @shirts.get_max
  min = @shirts.get_min
  max && min ? max - min : 0
end
```

Comment: or `max = @shirts.get_max || (return 0)`

Comment: So I got it to work by using the ternary operator you suggested and it outputs the range. However, I do not understand why it works in this case but not when you just do "max-min". I haven't changed the values of max and min since that code stayed the same, so how come it was nil without the ternary operator but works with the ternary operator?

Comment: `max && min` makes sure that both variables are not nil. Only if both variables are present the calculation may happen (as both `nil - 2` and `5 - nil` would raise an error). Unless both variables are present, the second branch will be returned.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but what I am asking is why max & min are not nil when you use the ternary operator but they are nil when I tried to just do "max-min"?

Comment: `max` and `min` are still nil, however the `mix - min` in the first branch will only be executed if both are present, else the second branch will be called. Sleep it over!